# How to count specific differences between columns in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, apply

I have a dataframe where I want to go through each column and count out how many times there is a difference of +1 (not -1!) between its row values and the row values of other columns. For instance, in column 2 there are 4 row values that are 1 greater than their column 1 equivalents, the first, third, fifth and sixth.

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
 v1  v2  v3  
  1   2   3   
  2   1   3  
  1   2   3   
  1   3   2   
  2   3   1   
  1   2   3  
 ")
```

It looks like an `apply` function would be useful here but I'm a bit stuck on how to use it.

The expected output would be something like a matrix of the counts where this occurs.

```
   V1 V2 V3
V1 -  4  2
V2 4  -  3
V3 2  3  -
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun it'd be some summary of the counts of the number of occurrences where this happens between the columns. I've edited the question to explain this.

Comment: isn't 3 between `V1` and `V3`? (1, 4, 5)

Comment: @Sotos in comparing V1 and V3 there are 2 times where there is a difference of 1 greater, in row 2 (2,3) and row 4 (1,2)

Comment: ok, so -1 is not acceptable

Comment: @Sotos correct, that's what I was trying to get across with '1 greater', there has to be a nicer way to put that!

Comment: `rowSums(apply(df[,c(1:3,1,3)], 1, diff) == 1)[-3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(colnames(df),function(v1){
      return(sapply(colnames(df),
                    function(v2){
                        return(sum(df[,v1]-df[,v2] == 1))
                    }))
  })

   v1 v2 v3
v1  0  4  2
v2  1  0  3
v3  1  1  0
```

If you want symmetric values use `abs(df[,v1]-df[,v2] == 1)` in the `sum` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This works as well:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
 v1  v2  v3  
 1   2   3   
 2   1   3  
 1   2   3   
 1   3   2   
 2   3   1   
 1   2   3")

ncols  <- ncol(df)
result <- matrix(nrow=ncols, ncol=ncols, 
                 dimnames = list(names(df),names(df)))

sapply(1:ncols, function(x) {
  result[(1:ncols)[-x],x] <<- colSums(df[,x]-df[,-x] == 1)
})

# Depending on whether you want a symmetric matrix or not:
result[lower.tri(result)] <- result[upper.tri(result)]
```

This gives you:

```
   v1 v2 v3
v1 NA  4  2
v2  4 NA  3
v3  2  3 NA
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a 'number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length' error for your function as it stands.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't replaced all the 'df' names with the name of the new dataframe I was trying out. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Result as a list (no hard-coded names, any number of columns etc.):

```
library(data.table)

df <- read.table(header=T, text="
 v1  v2  v3  
                 1   2   3   
                 2   1   3  
                 1   2   3   
                 1   3   2   
                 2   3   1   
                 1   2   3  
                 ")

dt <- data.table(df)

col_comb <- combn(names(dt), 2, simplify = FALSE)
names(col_comb) <- sapply(col_comb, paste0, collapse = "-")

res <- invisible(lapply(col_comb, function(comb) {
  return(dt[, sum(get(comb[2]) - get(comb[1]) == 1)])
}))
```

#### Result:

```
$`v1-v2`
[1] 4

$`v1-v3`
[1] 2

$`v2-v3`
[1] 3
```

#### 4 columns example:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
 v1  v2  v3  v4  
                 1   2   3   1
                 2   1   3   2
                 1   2   3   3
                 1   3   2   1
                 2   3   1   1
                 1   2   3   1
                 ")

# rest of code here
```

#### Result:

```
$`v1-v2`
[1] 4

$`v1-v3`
[1] 2

$`v1-v4`
[1] 0

$`v2-v3`
[1] 3

$`v2-v4`
[1] 2

$`v3-v4`
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following. The idea is to loop (using `sapply`) through the columns and calculate the difference and output the number of a difference exactly of 1. Same column comparisons produce a `NA`.

```
# function
foo <- function(i,y){
  a <- c(1:3) # number of data.frame columns
  a1 <- sapply(a, function(j,ii) if(a[j] == a[ii]) NA else sum((y[,ii] - y[,j]) == 1) ,i)
  a2 <- sapply(a, function(j,ii) if(a[j] == a[ii]) NA else sum((y[,j]  - y[,ii]) == 1) ,i)
  a1+a2-1
    }

sapply(1:ncol(df), foo, df)  
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    4    2
[2,]    4   NA    3
[3,]    2    3   NA
```